# Sum of reciprocals of prime-index-primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Let $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, $p_3=5$, $\ldots$ be an enumeration the prime numbers. If $q$ is a prime number, we call $p_q$ a prime-index-prime. A list of prime-index-primes can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A006450).

My question is:

> Does $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{p_i}}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{31}+\ldots$$ converges or diverges?

The graph below shows the values of the partial sums $S_n$ of the previous series from $n=1$ to $n=1184$, $n$ is the $x$-coordinate and $S_n$ is the $y$-coordinate.

[image: Partial sums of the series]

We can't conclude much by the graph. But my guess is that it diverges because, perhaps, it grows very, **very**, slow.

Comment: Growing "very very slowly" would seem to me to imply **convergence**, not divergence.

Comment: @user247327 : Not always. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^\infty {1\over k \ln k \ln \ln k}$, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link to the OEIS says that the series converges: "$\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1} {1\over a(n)}$ converges. In fact, $\displaystyle\sum_{n>N} {1\over a(n)} < {1\over \ln(N)}$, by the integral test. --- Jonathan Sondow, Jul 11 2012."

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Next time, I'll read all the informations. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's interesting to see a proof of the convergence. From PNT we have that $$p_{n}\sim n\log\left(n\right)
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty
 $ so $$p_{p_{n}}\sim p_{n}\log\left(p_{n}\right)\sim n\log^{2}\left(n\right)
 $$ and we can observe that, using the integral test, that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log^{2}\left(n\right)}\leq\frac{1}{2\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\log^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{1+2\log\left(2\right)}{2\log^{2}\left(2\right)}.$$